# Adding information to a google analytics pageview

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, traffic, google-analytics-api, pageviews

I use google analytics to monitor my traffic.  For some pages, I want to record extra information beyond just the page being viewed.  For example, if someone visits a profile page I might want to also record if that profile is a celebrity.

I don't want to artificially alter the URL for this.  Can I add data to a pageview like I can with GA events?  And of course, then I'd like to analyze traffic based on that data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to use the URL (which I wouldn't recommend) to send meta-data, you could send it as a second parameter in the `_trackPageview` call:

```
_gaq.push(["_trackPageview", "/custom-url-for-celebrity-view]);
```

The better way for you to do it, though, would be to use [Custom Variables](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html)

```
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "Page Type", "Celebrity Profile", 3]);
_gaq.push(["_trackPageview"]);
```

That way, your natural URL data is preserved, but the custom variable provides the meta data you'd like to know.

Comment: I specifically mentioned I didn't want to artificially alter the URLs in google analytics.  Your second suggestion, though, with custom variables looks like exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!